# Trying to wipe clean a headless server without plugging a monitor/keyboard?

Tags: server, headless

I have a server, which is hard to access. I could take it from the understairs "network mess". I want to use that server for some stuff that is security sensitive, so would prefer if I wiped the state clean.

I've looked here, but most replies seem old and/or associated with desktop installations. Is there a way to revert the ubuntu server installation to barebones and eliminate all services, port configurations and packages not in the initial installation?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you remove the disk? What is the server harware? can you plug in a serial console?

Comment: not familiar with the concept of a serial console, googling...

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out-of-band_management